# How to restructure my Django code?

Tags: django

I am new to Django.I want to create app that would enable selected users to login and then upload files that would latter be processed.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=80,blank=True)
    company = models.TextField(max_length=80, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()

class Document(models.Model):
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    company = forms.CharField()

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

malex.urls(application urls)

```
from malex.views import list
from malex.views import login 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list/$', list, name='list'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
]
```

project/urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^newp/', include('malex.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(user=cd['user'],password=cd['password'],company=cd['company'])
            if user is not None:
                if user is active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponse('Authenticated successfully')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid login')
    else:
        form=LoginForm()

    return render(request,'account/login.html',{'form': form})



def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
```

Now the login and upload operations are separated.
How to change my views and urls to have login first and upload latter?
Do I need to use Class based views with decorators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a custom login form and view.
2. use your localhost:8000 address as login template

   `(app) urlpatterns = [path('',views.loginview,name = 'login')]`

   `(project) urlpatterns = [path('', include('malex.urls')),)]`
3. extend your login template using `{% block content %}{% endblock %}`
4. use pass restrictions `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in template or view to let them access `upload section`.

Comment: Your idea sounds very good,just it seems that I have made a mistake with two view functions.It seems that it would not be so easy to refactor the code.

Comment: are you getting any error or want to restructure your code completely ? Your views.py code are fine, you just need to tweak your `url` and `templates` to get desired result .